# Вывод свойства инфоблока в Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

Можно ли в `Bitrix` настроить свойства инфоблока для вывода на странице со списком материалов этого инфоблока?

Comment: а вы через какой компонент выводите материалы инфоблока?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то речь о отображении свойств в списке элементов?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]